# How to override the User interface from Express Request

Tags: typescript, express, tsconfig

Im trying to define the properties of my User attributes that comes from the request of my auth service

My declaration to override express is

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user?: User;
    }

    interface User {
      name: string;
      token: string
    }
  }
}
```

But I still get a type error when I try to get user.name ( name doesn't exist of User)

I tried added the declaration to the tsconfig inside typesRoot but it didn't work neither

Any clue?

Comment: Show the error message. Did you try `req.user?.name`?

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put the module declaration inside a @type/express/index.d.ts to the tsconfig takes it